# Node JS Routes are not working on hosting server

Tags: node.js, express, routes, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have uploaded my node js app on my web hosting server.

The issue is the home route is working fine and rendering the ejs page from views directory. But when I go to any other route so it is showing 404 error.

Below is the sample code of two routes.

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

 res.render("landing");
});

app.get("/campgrounds", function(req, res) {

 res.render("campground", {
  campground: campground
 });

});
```

Please review the below I have uploaded and created the app using this option in my cpanel. Root route is working fine and showing the homepage.

[image]

Comment: Add some details about how you are uploading to server and running the app there

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan updated pelase review.

Comment: Is it different when you test the app on your computer?

Comment: node js application in folder?

Answer (score 1):

Add .htaccess with the below configuration in your domain root directory. In case your app folder is located in a subdomain, your .htaccess should be in the subdomain root directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```